# Spring 3 @Autowire in tests

Tags: java, spring-3, spring-test

I have one irritating problem right now.
My tests fail due to an autowire.

> Could not autowire field: private k.dao.CompanyDao k.dao.CompanyDaoTest.companyDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [k.dao.CompanyDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

I think @ContextConfiguration can be the problem?

The test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:**/servlet-context.xml", "classpath:**/root-context.xml", "classpath:**/ccc-jpa.xml" })
public final class CompanyDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private CompanyDao companyDao;

    @Test
    public void testTest() {

    }
}
```

CompanyDao

```
public interface CompanyDao extends GenericDao<Company> {

}
```

CompanyDaoJpa

```
@Repository("companyDao")
public class CompanyDaoJpa extends GenericDaoJpa<Company> implements CompanyDao {

    public CompanyDaoJpa() {
        super(Company.class);
    }
}
```

GenericDao

```
public interface GenericDao<T extends DomainObject> {

    public T get(Long id);

    public List<T> getAll();

    public T save(T object);

    public T delete(T object);

}
```

servlet-context.xml

```
    <annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="k"/>
```

Comment: What do the other Spring XML configurations look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess your test doesn't load `servlet-context.xml` at all.

You reference `servlet-context.xml` as a classpath resource, but `servlet-context.xml` is usually located under `WEB-INF`, which is not a part of application classpath. Note that Spring doesn't complain about missing config files when they are referenced with wildcards ( `classpath:**/servlet-context.xml`), so that your test starts silently even if config files cannot be found.

There are no good ways to access Spring xml files located in `WEB-INF` from unit tests. If you want to run tests against them, you need to move them to the classpath (i.e. to something like `src` or `resources`, depending on your project layout). Since `DispatcherServlet` and `ContextLoaderListener` expect to find these files under `WEB-INF`, you also need to reconfigure them using their respective `contextConfigLocation` parameters. For example, in the case of `DispatcherServlet`:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:**/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem :)